# How can I register a Filter in AEM 6.3 with the httpcontext that is called first in the chain during HTTP request processing

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

How can I register a Filter in AEM 6.3 with the httpcontext that is called first in the chain. The goal here is to intercept the request coming into AEM and add a HTTP header. Basically trying to set the HTTP header value with user information for SSO login. This pattern used to work in CQ6.1 and stopped working now.

Answer (score 3):

AEM 6.3 does not introduce any new logic for Sling Filters.

You can check the ordering/priority of your filter using `/system/console/request` traces. The filter priority is determined by the `order` property of the `@SlingFilter` attribute as shown below.

```
@SlingFilter(
    label = "Filter Label",
    description = "implementation of a Sling Filter",
    generateComponent = true, 
    generateService = true, 
    order = 0, 
    scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST) // REQUEST, INCLUDE, FORWARD, ERROR, COMPONENT (REQUEST, INCLUDE, COMPONENT)
    public class MySlingFilter implements Filter {
       ////// Implementation
    }
```

The **order** property has following rules:

- It defaults to Integer.MAX_VALUE which means your filter will be at the end of filter chain if this property is not set.
- The value can be 0 or negative to promote the filter in order to be called earlier.

Check and change this property to see if this helps with your issue.

Comment: Felix SCR is in maintenance mode, new users should use the answer provided by @Anthony Piontkowski

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of Apache Felix doesn't exist annotation @SlingFilter and you can use mapping as below.

```
@Component(service = Filter.class, property = {
        EngineConstants.SLING_FILTER_SCOPE + "=" + EngineConstants.FILTER_SCOPE_REQUEST,
        EngineConstants.SLING_FILTER_PATTERN + "=..."
})
public class SomeFilter implements Filter {
```